# testing helpers with 'haml_tag'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, haml

```
module FooHelper
  def foo
    haml_tag(:div) do
      haml_content("bar")
    end
  end
end
```

When I test this I get:

NoMethodError: undefined method `haml_tag'

This code is perfectly valid and works in a development/production environment.

It's something to do with having the haml helpers properly loaded in the test environment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the Rails test scaffold isn't including `Haml::Helpers` in its context. If you're using `Test::Unit`, you can probably just include it yourself in the test class. You'll also want to run [`Haml::Helpers#init_haml_helpers`](http://haml.hamptoncatlin.com/docs/rdoc/classes/Haml/Helpers.html#M000005) in the test setup so that all the Haml stuff is properly initialized.

Comment: This just gives me another error:

NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.html?
    haml (2.0.9) lib/haml/helpers.rb:349:in `haml_tag'

Comment: What is the proper way to call it from within the class? `class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase    include Haml::Helpers    [something here].init_haml_helpers   end`  – What goes there?

Comment: You need to call it before each test case, in whatever context the Haml helpers will run.

Comment: class ActiveSupport::TestCase;
  include Haml::Helpers;

  def setup;
    init_haml_helpers;
  end;
end

Comment: ...which is exactly what @nex3 said, I just must've screwed it up the first time around.

Answer (score 0):

http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#init_haml_helpers-instance_method